# How to redirect user directly to /login and not show layout / dashboard in static export on NextJs 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using NextJS v13 and doing next export for deployment.
2 problems I am facing:

1. If a user goes to / url, how to redirect them directly and always to /login.
2. To add logic to check if a user is logged in or not and redirect accordingly.

Any way I can ensure that user does not see flashes of some other page before being redirected correctly.

If a global loader would work, how can I go about to implement it?

I tried to solve the above by putting the logic in a useEffect but the layout of the website flashes across the screen before redirecting to the intended page.

Since I am doing static export, I am not able to use the async redirects feature in next config or the getInitialProp or getServerProps functions.

Comment: There is no way to do that server side when you statically export your website. Try using the serve with a dynamic build and validate the authentication state of the user on a per-request basis on the server.

Comment: I can only do  statically export for the project as of now.

Comment: Sadly there is no way to achieve your goal then.